# What quick release lead options are available for use in poor weather conditions?

Tags: leash-training, leashes

We've recently added a dog to our family and bought a cheap lead.

It's been a pain to use over the last few months.  On cold winter mornings, the lead was virtually impossible to clip back on; definitely impossible with gloves. Looking on the internet, you can pay what you want for quick release leads, but what type of quick release leads would be ideal, and reliable, in these circumstances?

Comment: Please see [What to avoid asking](http://pets.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for some details.

Comment: I've tried to rephrase to make the question less subjective, but still provide what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My lead's P-Clip got all stiff and as my wife is beginning to suffer from arthritis we searched and searched for pain free solution to this age old problem.  The answer for us was a fairly new product called a Magloc.  It has a magnet that connect the lead to the collar and then some clever little jaws hold it in place.  The best bit is the release, just squeeze the side tabs and it pulls straight off.  In fact, it helps a bit if your dog is actually pulling away when you want to release it.  I got ours here... [magloc shop](http://www.maglocshop.co.uk) and we love it.

Answer (score 3):

replace the clip with a carabiner, it's not quick release but much easier to handle than fighting a rusted spring with a little tab